# Apply CSS on particular <a> in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have following div in HTML. Now I was wondering is there a way to apply CSS to just first 2 `<a>` and different Css on 3rd `<a>`

```
<div id="contain">
    <div> 
        <a href="#" id="A">A</a>
        <a href="#" id="B">B</a>
        <a href="#" id="C">C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contain a {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I want to apply above Css to only first 2 `<a>` in Div.

Thanks for help. :)

Comment: A suggestion, you can also use http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/W27es/ if a user is redundant to add classes to his HTML, solution is only better for this particular example, this has max compatibility without declaring classes in your HTML

Comment: Getting confused in so many great answers. :) So finally which do you think will be most useful across all possible condition. nth-of-type() or the above fiddle. Thanks:)

Comment: Each has their uniqueness, [Milind's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23148467/1542290) is suitable for the users who doesn't want to support older IE, the suggestion [I gave you above](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23148446/apply-css-on-particular-a-in-a-div?noredirect=1#comment35396337_23148446) is ideal when you want to support old version of IE but YOU DON NOT WANT TO DECLARE CLASSES YOURSELF, and [Helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23148497/1542290) *(Username)* answer is max compatible across browsers but you need to declare classes by yourself.. but the max optimum answer is by Milind

Comment: Thanks a lot. So finally i guess i will go with nth-of-type().

Comment: Absolutely fine if you are not supporting vintage versions of Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) to target the first two elements...

```
#contain a:nth-child(-n+2){
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FKZtn/18/)**

**Update:** using  [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

```
 #contain a:nth-of-type(-n+2){
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color:red;
 }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/FKZtn/19/)**

Comment: This should be perfect answer according to OP's requirement

Comment: Also, you can use `nth-of-type()` which is a better thing here, say if any dynamic element generates between the `a` tag, your selector will break... check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/FKZtn/19/) vs [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/FKZtn/20/) *(Second one with the `nth-child` fails)*

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks for explaining. I guess nth-of-type() would be best suited here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS classes, like so:

```
<div id="contain">
                    <div style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;"> 
                    <a href="#"  id="A" class="specialLink">A</a>
                    <a href="#"  id="B" class="specialLink">B</a> 
                    <a href="#"  id="C">C</a>
         </div>           
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS, you do:

```
#contain a.specialLink {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
           }
```

The "`.specialLink`" part makes it so only elements with that class get that styling.

Comment: what if OP cannot change the HTML?

Comment: What in the question made you think the OP couoldn't change the HTML?  If he can't, then one of the other answers will work excellently - css selectors are very broad, indeed.  This looked like a fairly first-time css-user question to me, so I explained a fairly fundamental part of CSS - classes.

Comment: I always go with maximum bad possibilities because I've seen many users forget to specify complete requirements and the next thing you get is that I cannot change my HTML, or they say is that even I can do this, what if I want to apply style to 99 elements and not the single one? Providing optimum answer will never harm anyone.. :)

Comment: An excellent standpoint to take.  Again, considering the question (which appeared fairly new-to-css to me) I feel like classes are a fairly easy way to explain these - less likely for the OP to merely copy/paste blindly.  But I can certainly respect more sophisticated answers involving more advanced selectors, too.  You bring up an excellent point.

Comment: Yea, as far as your answer goes, I've voted long way back, just for a reason that your answer has max compatibility as far as cross browser is concerned :)

Comment: Indeed, this answer works , if the browser does not support the CSS3 features

Answer (score 1):

The first line will apply css to first two a and last to last a tag

```
$('#contain').find('a').css('some property');
$('#contain').find('a:last').css('some property');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have to set css to some items use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iterations = 0;
    var countOfItems = 2; // how many <a> you need to change
    $('div#contain').find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).css({ "margin":"10px 20px 10px 20px", "text-decoration":"none" , "display":"inline-block"});
        iterations ++;
        if(iterations == countOfItems)
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I would not recommend solving this with Javascript when it can easily be solved with some simple CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ID` selector:

```
#A { ... }
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `nth-child()` of CSS3 like this:

```
#contain a:nth-child(number)
{
   css declarations;
}
```

Where the `number` is the index of element.

For more info about `nth-child()` please refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: I don't want to use id so was trying for some other way

Answer (score 0):

U can try -

```
             <a href="#"  id="A" style="margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">A</a>
             <a href="#"  id="B" style="margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">B</a> 

             <a href="#"  id="C" style="different attributes which u want">C</a>
```